# How to deal with name column in Scikitlearn randomforest classifier. python 3

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, countvectorizer

I have a dataframe containing 13 columns. Among 13 three columns are string. One string column is simple male and female which I converted to 1 and 0 using

> pd.get_dummies()

2nd column contains three different types of string so, easily converted to array using

> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

No issue at all. Problem is my third and last column contains large number of names. if I try to convert using Countvectorizer it converts the names into long unreadable strings.

> df['name']=Countvectorizer.fit_transform(df.name)

if I try to convert back it to dataframe as shown in other examples on stackoverflow page in this case I get this

> 245376      (0, 14297)\t1\n  (1, 5843)\t1\n  (1, 13365)...
>   245377      (0, 14297)\t1\n  (1, 5843)\t1\n  (1, 13365)...

Name: supplier_name, dtype: object

and this next code results Memory Error

> df['name'] =pd.DataFrame(CV.fit_transform(df.name).toarray(),columns=CV.get_feature_names())

I have looked that issue as well. 
Question: is there any way best to use this name column in numeric forms except above mentioned. Or any other idea how to improve this so that data perfectly fit in **Randomforest classifier**. As, Dataframe is quit large containing **123790 rows**. Thank you in advance for help or suggestion.

Comment: What type of problem are you solving (Classification, regression, ..etc.)? First you should analyze if you are sure you want `name` feature in the model or not. Show some samples and what you want to do with them.

Comment: I want to create simple predictive model using scikitlearn random forest. Its actually classification problem. I have 13 columns last column is id. Based on 12 columns I want to predict ids after training the model.  this name column is not null at all.  which is most important column I can not remove it.

Comment: Is the name unique for each row? If not and they are from a small set, then you can do one hot encoding for them.

Comment: I tried that but result 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'CountVectorizer'

Comment: I dont think that `CountVectorizer` will be of any help here. Please show some code what you tried and also some samples of names.

Comment: `C2['sex']=pd.get_dummies(C2['sex'])
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv= CountVectorizer()
formOfCompany = pd.DataFrame(cv.fit_transform(C2.form_of_company).toarray(),columns=cv.get_feature_names())

C2=C2.join(formOfCompany)
C2.drop(['form_of_company'], axis = 1, inplace = True, errors = 'ignore')`

Comment: CountVectorizer will change the single name column into multiple columns of word frequency. And I have a feeling you dont want that. Show some samples of `names` columns.

Comment: `United 
Horst
thal
desk
Potzel
Satu
haus
OMV
haus
via`
these are some sample. These names are repeating as well. One form of company can have many names. here in my database I have 123790 rows. What do you suggest about tfidf? I tried this one but same Memory Error.

Comment: Or any idea how to map these names to numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134681/discussion-between-vivek-kumar-and-ch-haxam).

Comment: I figured it out. I mapped the unique names with integers and converted them them to dataframe. Later I replaced the old column with new one. I created a separate function find the name with key.

Comment: Great. Make sure to train multiple classifiers on your data and compare their outputs.

Comment: I am doing it, Thanks for help Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Well name is a unique thing and an id kind of use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` after storing the original to a separate list. It will automatically convert the names to a serial number.

Also, note if it's a unique thing you should remove names during predicting.